# naming your graphql mutations in react-apollo

Tags: graphql, apollo, react-apollo, graphcool

consider the following

```
const createBob1 = gql`
    mutation createBob2($var: data) {
        createBob3(var: $var) {
            id
        }
    }
`
```

at three levels, we're naming the mutation:

1. createBob1 defines the graphql document
2. createBob2 defines the apollo mutation
3. createBob3 defines the graphql resolver function to call

(I think?)

Has anyone settled on a naming convention for how to keep all three names consistent? Do you name them all the same?

Comment: This is not a good question for SO as there is no right or wrong, just opinions. Have a look at the docs here on what they suggest for naming queries :http://graphql.org/learn/queries/#operation-name

Comment: I disagree. Plenty of opinion-based questions are asked on SO and it's useful to see how other developers approach it. That way, we can develop opinions outside our own (and the formal docs that you linked)